# solution of $\frac{1}{x}=\infty$

Tags: equation-solving, calculus-and-analysis

Is there a way to obtain solution $x=0$ for the equation $\frac{1}{x}=\infty$ in Mathematica?

I tried `Solve`, `Reduce`, `FindInstance` and with different options, but Mathematica keeps beeping on me that system contains an infinite object or it gives `{}` as answer, meaning no solution. I tried with `Infinity` and `ComplexInfinity`.

Maple gives $x=0$ as solution.

Why is `0` not a solution to $\frac{1}{x}=\infty$ ? Since `1/0` gives `ComplexInfinity`

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Some attempts

```
ClearAll[x];
eq = 1/x == ComplexInfinity;
Solve[eq, x, Reals, Method -> "Reduce"]
Solve[eq, x]
Reduce[eq, x]
FindInstance[eq, x]
SolveAlways[eq, x]
```

Maple:

[image]

Is there some deep mathematical reason why $0$ can not be solution to this equation according to Mathematica, and is there some workaround?

Comment: "Is there some deep mathematical reason why 0 can not be solution to this equation[...]?" 0 doesn't contain any directional information. 1/x with x tending to 0 is infinity if 0 is approached from a positive direction, but what about a negative or imaginary one?

Comment: Why not to solve `1/x==a` and then go to a limit?

Comment: As @AlexeiBoulbitch suggested, `Limit[x /. Solve[1/x == a, x][[1]], a -> Infinity]`

Comment: @AlexeiBoulbitch because I do not know what the equation looks like before hand. This is done in a program, the equation (generated by another part of the program) can be anything and it needs to solve for $x$. It is not an interactive session where one looks at the screen and then decides what to do.

Comment: One obstacle is that we do not even have `ComplexInfinity == ComplexInfinity`. This expression does not evaluate further; `Equal` (`==`) is not defined on `ComplexInfinity`. We would need `SameQ` (`===`), and I'm not sure if `Solve` and the like can work with that...you might need a full workaround, like `Solve[(x |-> Piecewise[{{1/x, x != 0}, {0, x == 0}}])[s] == 0, s]`, where we have replaced `1/x` with a different function defined at 0, but I'm not sure if this is an option for you.

Comment: You can also do something less potentially breaking by using a custom-defined `infinity` instead of `0` as the value at `x==0`: `infinity /: infinity^(-1) = 0; Solve[(x |-> Piecewise[{{1/x, x != 0}, {infinity, x == 0}}])[s] == infinity, s]`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It makes sense on the [complex projective line](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/projective+line). If you can restrict your computations to that domain, there shouldn't be a problem.

```
eq = 1/x == ComplexInfinity;
Join @@ Map[
  Solve[#, x] &,
  1/$i == 0 /. Solve[eq /. ComplexInfinity -> $i, $i]
  ]

(*  {{x -> 0}}  *)
```

(You can put `$i` in a `Module` etc. if you want to turn it into a function.)

Comment: No arithmetic operations are defined on the complex projective space, in particular, on the complex projective line (see [Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complex_projective_space)). In complex analysis the complex plane is compactified by adding `ComplexInfinity` (in WL notation) to continuously extend fractional-linear functions on `Union[Complexes,ComplexInfinity]`, no more and no less (see [Encyclopedia of Mathematics](https://encyclopediaofmath.org/wiki/Fractional-linear_function)).

Comment: I'd like to stress again thar the Riemann sphere is a topological notion, not an algebraic notion.

Comment: It should be "compactified by the addition..." in the above.

Comment: @user64494 I changed the reference. I hope it’s clearer, but the phrase I used (which was never “Riemann sphere”) is still correct.

Comment: I repeat "No arithmetic operations (something like `1/x` )are defined on the complex projective space, in particular, on the complex projective line (see [Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complex_projective_space)". This is not an algebraic structure.

Comment: @user64494 I repeat: Algebraic geometry has been using rational functions on the projective line/space for over a century. Beyond that, [meromorphic functions](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/projective+line#analytic_projective_lines) may be naturally viewed as functions $\Bbb C \rightarrow P^1(\Bbb C)$.  See ref.

Answer (score 4):

Because both `ComplexInfinity \[Element] Complexes` and `Infinity \[Element] Reals` return `False`, the equation `1/x==\[Infinity]` makes no sense in traditional math. Maple developers must master their math knowledge.

Comment: BTW, the definition `1/0==ComplexInfinity` contradicts traditional math.

Comment: See [Encyclopedia of Mathematics](https://encyclopediaofmath.org/wiki/Infinity) and [Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Infinity) to this end.

Comment: “the equation `1/x==Infinity` makes no sense in traditional math” — this is just plain wrong, unless by “traditional” you mean school-kid math.  Algebraic geometry has been dealing with such equations for something like 150 years.

Answer (score 2):

There is a way of doing this

```
expr := Solve[1/x == ComplexInfinity, x]

expr
(* Solve::infc: The system 1/x==ComplexInfinity contains an infinite object ComplexInfinity. *)
(* Solve[1/x == ComplexInfinity, x] *)

Unprotect[Solve];
Solve[1/u_ == ComplexInfinity, u_] := {u -> 0}
Protect[Solve];

expr
(* {x -> 0} *)
```

As a general rule, I would think this is a very unwise thing to do, but as a bodge to fix a particular problem, it might work.